# What is the meaning of “shape-up” in this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests

> The shape-up has been gone for many decades, much of New
>   Jersey shipping has moved away from Hoboken.

Comment: It would help if you cited where the sentence came from: [On the waterfront p77](https://books.google.com/books?id=OER7__j0wwoC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=The+shape-up+has+been+gone+for+many+decades,+much+of+New+Jersey+shipping+has+moved+away+from+Hoboken&source=bl&ots=9swrGXqBFv&sig=cc_ywa_i4N8xFt6u0qUd4eNJxek&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE2bXltYPMAhXLwiYKHfquBUAQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=shape-up&f=false)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the context is unclear and no reference to the source is given in the question.

Comment: @Danialkhojasteh the point isn't that you have the book.  It's that you didn't point us to it.  I'm trying to help you write a better question so you can get better answers. Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/318667/edit) your question to include it.  Comments don't count.

Answer (score 1):

The ["shape up"](http://depts.washington.edu/dock/longshore_intro.shtml) is a system whereby unskilled manual laborers like longshoreman show up at the start of a workday at a work location (the docks for longshoremen) to compete for employment for the day.